# Why does the HTML5 standard recommend inserting a newline after the <html> start tag?

Tags: html

[According to the HTML5 Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#writing):

> It is suggested that newlines be inserted after the DOCTYPE, after any comments that are before the root element, after the html element's start tag (if it is not omitted), and after any comments that are inside the html element but before the head element.

What is the reasoning behind this recomendation? Is there a difference between writing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just helps improve readability, the code is processed exactly the same way.

Answer (score -2):

There are some issues with parsing self-closing tags that can be a bit odd in certain situations.

For example, in HTML5 it is perfectly valid to write an unordered list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello
    <li>World
</ul>
```

The `<li>` tag implies `</li><li>` if there is no closing `</li>` present immediately before it.  What's weird about this is the new lines in your code actually affect the way your list renders to the browser.

Unfortunately you cannot see this in jsfiddle, but you can see how the spacing issues affect a normally written list differently due to spacing, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li><li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Differs from

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LGq9k/1/

I would imagine that the weird spacing oddities are the reason they suggest generally-accepted syntactical spacing and line breaks should be used, but who knows?

Comment: You modified ul and li to not have their default functionality, making them effectively similar to div and span. The same thing would happen if you wrote `<span>Hello</span><span>World</span>`. Not quite the same because span is `display:inline;` by default, but there isn't an element that is `display:inline-block;` by default as far as I know.